# Azure function didn't realize the trigger on deployment but that work in local

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

My azure function works correctly locally but when I deploy it on azure. It will return this message:

```
Deployment successful. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Syncing triggers...
Querying triggers...
No HTTP triggers found.
Uploading settings...
Added the following settings:
- AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags
- FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT
11:43:54 AM: Ignored the following settings that were already the same:
- FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME
11:43:54 AM: WARNING: This operation will not delete any settings in "vietnam-trademark-scraper-dev-test". You must manually delete settings if desired.
11:43:54 AM: Excluded the following settings:
- AzureWebJobsStorage
11:43:54 AM: Error: Error "appSettings.properties with value "1" must be of type string." occurred in serializing the payload - "StringDictionary".
```

in local, I see all trigger work:

[image: trigger]

[image: project structure]

I use Python V2 model Azure Functions triggers. I deploy it with a dedicated plan.

I try to search for this problem on google and have no idea to fix it. Can someone explain this problem and suggested me some solutions? Thanks

Comment: Please check [one of my workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74686213/16630138) to fix the issue you are facing and do let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @HariKrishna, I added this setting and redeployed and it works. But I don't know how it works? Can you explain it? I see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators#update-app-settings) add this to local.settings.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that it worked for you by adding the setting `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags:EnableWorkerIndexing` and shown the practical in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74686213/16630138) of my workarounds.

> I added this setting and redeployed and it works. But I don't know how it works? Can you explain it?

It is because Microsoft explicitly mentioned to add that application setting for running the Python Programming v2 model in Azure.

Whatever the values we have added related to `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags` are not ready to run in production but can be experimental before they are released completely as defined in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsfeatureflags) of Azure Functions App Settings.

And also, in the V2 Programming model, multiple workers (`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT`) of Python environment is not yet supporting in greater than 1 so this setting needs to be added as a Feature flag to work.

Refer to the GitHub [Article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Worker-Indexing-Changes) on Azure Functions Host of Worker Indexing Changes to Python Environment for related more information.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to make sure that `function_app.py` executes without any errors. If you have imports on the top which may have been resulting in errors, try moving them to a `try except` block.

```py
# before
from azure.functions import FunctionApp
from src import foo, bar, baz

app = FunctionApp()
```

```py
# after
from azure.functions import FunctionApp

try:
    from src import foo, bar, baz
except:
    pass

app = FunctionApp()
```

Comment: I think you should look at the above answer for my case. I got this bug because I lost an essential setting for running this function on the cloud.

Comment: I understand that your problem was different, but I added this answer because this is post is one of the top results on google for this error.

Comment: I had a similar problem, apparently the imports are not always showing errors and are very sensitive even in the requirements.txt file you provide...