# Azure Functions Python error - no job functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to run locally my Azure Functions using python and the error message I get is the following:

```
[2023-03-03T11:34:59.832Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup 
code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
```

I created my project with this command and did not change anything in the generated code:

```
func init LocalFunctionProj --python -m V2
```

When I try to run the app with this command then I get the error message mentioned above:

```
func start --verbose
```

I am running this on python v3.10. Also, when I tried to create the V1 python function it worked without any problems..

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: How is your init.py file looks like?

Comment: I dont know if this is the cause of the problem, but Azure functions do not support python 3.10 yet : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode%2Cbash&pivots=python-mode-configuration#the-python-interpreter-isnt-supported-by-azure-functions-python-worker

Comment: For me its working https://i.imgur.com/4b6YhRv.png - Python V2 Azure Functions project with the python version 3.10.10

Comment: Have you activated virtual environment before starting/running the function?

Comment: Will try to see the environment.

Comment: For V2 there is no init.py, I think

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I was missing a line in local.settings.json

> "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"

compared to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#triggers-and-inputs).

```
// local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING": "<AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING>",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<azure-storage-connection-string>",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

Comment: This tip worked for me.
I suspect there are a raft of reasons this can happen, and No Help from the dev environment. (Grrr...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been struggling with this issue for a a long time. Kudos for sharing this answer. Helped be big time!

Answer (score 4):

Using the same commands, I have created and tested in my local environment - Python 3.10.10 v2 model Azure Functions Project:

[image]

In the terminal, changed the path using `cd .\LocalFunctionProj\` for running the function `func start --verbose`
[image]

I have provided the practical solution working both locally and in Azure Cloud for the Python v2 model - SO #[74671905](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74686213)

Cause of your error might be a typical code mistake in any of the code files such as `function_app.py`, `local.settings.json`, `host.json`, or check the Azurite emulator is installed in VS Code Extensions and in running state.

**Code Snippets**:
**function_app.py**:

```py
import azure.functions as  func
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello") # HTTP Trigger
def  test_function(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
return  func.HttpResponse("HttpTrigger1 function processed a request!!!")
```

**requirements.txt**

```
azure-functions
```

**local.settings.json**:

```json
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
}
}
```

host.json

```json
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
    "samplingSettings": {
    "isEnabled": true,
    "excludedTypes": "Request"
    }
}
},
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.15.0, 4.0.0)"
    }
}
```

If all the code and configuration is correct, try activating virtual environment (Python [article](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)) and then run the function:

```py
py -m pip install --user virtualenv
py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate
func start --verbose
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check it out and follow your steps...

Comment: I think the use of the python environment and the use of parameter on Azure did the difference. However, I found that for some reason the first deploy did not work. I used the Azure Plugins deploy button and that made it work. Really strange to be honest

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I received this error because I had an older version of Azure Function Tools installed that didn't support the v2 Python function model.  I had created my function using the VS Code template rather than the CLI.  To resolve, I simply upgraded my Functions Core Tools.  On a Mac:

```bash
$ brew upgrade azure-functions-core-tools@4
```

One other thing I did -- which I don't think actually made a difference -- was to annotate my Python function with a function name, and change the access level from `FUNCTION` to `ANONYMOUS`, both of which came from [this documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python).  The out-of-the-box code had:

```py
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="myFunc")
def myFunc(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  ...
```

but I changed it to:

```py
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.function_name("MyFunc")
@app.route(route="myFunc")
def my_func(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  ...
```

In addition, I had to ensure that I had Azurite (the Azure Storage emulator) running before starting my function.  Ensure you have the VS Code extension installed, then run "Azurite: Start".

Hope that helps someone else who was stuck on this for a little while like I was!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for my azure function, and the solution was adding :

```
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
```

to my local.settings.json, because you are debugging in local.
Thanks to @Yasufuk